# How do I extract this field using JQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

JQ makes me irrationally angry and I despise its very existence. I have been trying to extract the value of the `tf-name` key for 30 minutes and I'm going to become a hermit if I have to make another attempt at this. Please, how do I get `tmp` as a a result?

```json
➜  aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=tf-name,Values=tmp --profile=test | jq   
                               
{
  "ResourceTagMappingList": [
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:s3:::stack-hate-1234567890salt",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name",
          "Value": "hatestack"
        },
        {
          "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id",
          "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:6666666666666:stack/FSStack/hate-hate-hate-123456789"
        },
        {
          "Key": "tf-name",
          "Value": "tmp"
        },
        {
          "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id",
          "Value": "hatebucket1234"
        },
        {
          "Key": "aws-cdk:auto-delete-objects",
          "Value": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Inian thanks for your answer. Was 1am last night and I posted this as I was heading to bed. I'm going to leave it up despite the downvote because of your answer quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite simple to extract, once you know the type of the top level objects. You can see `ResourceTagMappingList` is a list of records, so it should have a `[]` notation following it, which I think most beginners with `jq` tend to miss out. So

```
.ResourceTagMappingList[].Tags | from_entries."tf-name"
```

should get you the desired value. See [jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Num7Oz9uNK)

The way it works is, the `from_entries` function takes an array of objects with key names `key` and `value` and transforms it to a value only pair. From there, we extract only the key name `tf-name`. The special double quotes are needed because the key name here contains a meta-character `-`, which should be quoted to treat the whole string as the key name.

Another way would be to use a `select` statement like below

```
.ResourceTagMappingList[].Tags[] | select(.Key  == "tf-name").Value
```